# Memory leak introduced in V3.8 of Google Maps Javascript (observed in IE 9)

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-leaks, google-maps-api-3

I have working examplecode included that shows the leaking in IE 9. (1 Gb in a couple of minutes). THIS MEMORY LEAK DOES NOT OCCUR WHEN YOU CHANGE V3.8 TO V3.7!!! So my guess is it is introduced in v3.8!
The code seems to work in Chrome/Firefox but I am working on a C# Winform app,
 and use the embedded .NET webcontrol, a COM wrapper around IE.
Already tried the gecko .NET component, but that is no alternative for me.

I am stuck here and desperate, so if anybody would be so kind to provide a solution...

Thnx
Rob

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>Memoryleak in IE</title>

      <style type="text/css">
            html
            {
            }
            body
            {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }

        </style>
        <style type="text/css">
            .context
            {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #4444ff;
                font-size: small;
            }
            a:hover div
            {
                background: #00eeee;
            }
        </style>

      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;v=3.8" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

         var coords = [
    -115.821139332819,51.2247937004413,
    -115.821139332819,51.2247937004413,
    -115.820783024602,51.2247102926052,
    -115.820783024602,51.2247102926052,
    -115.820327685708,51.2246117850904,
    -115.820327685708,51.2246117850904,
    -115.819759388578,51.2244962798047,
    -115.819759388578,51.2244962798047,
    -115.819290270032,51.2244074438906,
    -115.819290270032,51.2244074438906,
    -115.818926957722,51.2243299769159,
    -115.818926957722,51.2243299769159,
    -115.818338387318,51.2242059504634,
    -115.818338387318,51.2242059504634,
    -115.817977304212,51.2241249042188,
    -115.817977304212,51.2241249042188,
    -115.817599143301,51.224042310143,
    -115.817599143301,51.224042310143,
    -115.817134937747,51.2239589216431,
    -115.817134937747,51.2239589216431,
    -115.816536085049,51.2238583513406,
    -115.816536085049,51.2238583513406,
    -115.816082549208,51.2237586568853,
    -115.816082549208,51.2237586568853,
    -115.815700862212,51.2236505400057,
    -115.815700862212,51.2236505400057,
    -115.815357631111,51.223555251529,
    -115.815357631111,51.223555251529,
    -115.814809515585,51.2234021852219,
    -115.814809515585,51.2234021852219,
    -115.814355814815,51.2232968327074,
    -115.814355814815,51.2232968327074,
    -115.813999142875,51.2231965005283,
    -115.813999142875,51.2231965005283,
    -115.813647699181,51.2230910623849,
    -115.813647699181,51.2230910623849,
    -115.813026822773,51.2229353329219,
    -115.813026822773,51.2229353329219,
    -115.812582641159,51.2228335929039,
    -115.812582641159,51.2228335929039,
    -115.812013680777,51.2226994808324,
    -115.812013680777,51.2226994808324,
    -115.811661976828,51.2225955792611,
    -115.811661976828,51.2225955792611,
    -115.811254131518,51.2224819086399,
    -115.811254131518,51.2224819086399,
    -115.810894380211,51.2223965803553,
    -115.810894380211,51.2223965803553,
    -115.810314308135,51.2222515485398,
    -115.810314308135,51.2222515485398,
    -115.809965253975,51.2221524009482];


        var myPano = null;
        var mySVC  = null;
        var sv     = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
        var teller = 0;
        var tmr    = null;

        function startStreetviewMode(lat, lon)
        {
            try
            {
                var svPanoramaOptions = {
                    visible:          true,
                    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                    linksControl:     true,
                    addressControl:   true,
                    panControl:       true,
                    zoomControl:      false,
                    imageDateControl: false,
                    position:         new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
                    pov: {
                         heading: 180,
                         pitch:   0,
                         zoom:    1
                         }
                    };

                myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"), svPanoramaOptions);
                myPano.setVisible(true);

                svPanoramaOptions = null;
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                alert("startStreetviewMode, " + err.source + ':' + err.message);
            }
       }

       function SVPanoInitialized(SVLocation)
       {
       }

       function handleSVError(errorCode)
       {
       }


       function showStreet(lat, lng)
       {
           try
           {
               sv.getPanoramaByLocation(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 50, function (data, status)
               {
                   if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK)
                   {
                       myPano.setPov({
                           heading: 180,
                           pitch:   10,
                           zoom:    1
                       });
                       myPano.setPano(data.location.pano);
                       myPano.setVisible(true);
                       data   = null;
                       status = null;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       handleSVError(status);
                   }
               });
            }
            catch (err)
            {
                alert("showStreet, " + err.source + ':' + err.message);
            }
        }

        function showit()
        {
            // Keep looping through array
            teller = teller + 2;
            if (teller > 80) teller = 0;

            // Show streetview to demonstrate leak
            showStreet(coords[teller + 1], coords[teller]);
        }

        function init()
        {
            startStreetviewMode(coords[teller + 1], coords[teller]);
          window.setInterval(this.showit, 750);
     }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">
        <div id="pano" style="width: 1024px; height: 768px" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unscoped (and global scope) variables are know to cause memory leaks.
I would suggest you make sure that all variables are correctly scoped to function-locals.

Comment: Thnx for your answer. I did some more research and concluded it is V3.8 related!